# display certain buttons using jQuery with switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html I have many buttons and I want to be able to show only specific button once a certain imagine had been clicked by using switch statements so far, this is what i had tried

HTML:

```
<div id = "displayedImages">
<ol>
      <li class="ui-state-default">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="background-position: -0px -0px" title=" Pink Flower" data-designName="pink Flower"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="background-position: -0px -100px" title="red Rocks" data-designName="red Rocks"></a>
 </li>
</ol>

<div id="buttons" style="display: none;"> 
  <ol>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="background-position: -50px -0px" title="first button" data-designName="first button"></a>
  </li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="background-position: -80px -1px" title="second button" data-designName="second button"></a>
 </li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="background-position: -301px -1px" title="third button" data-designName="third button"></a>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery 
    //jQuery("#buttons").show("blind");
            console.log("buttons clicked"); 
            switch(jQuery(event.target).attr("data-designName")){
            case "pink Flower":
            target = "first button";
                break;
            case "red Rocks":
                break;


            }
        }
```

Comment: Click an image then get one button to push? or multiple buttons? Initially how many images are there? Once an image is chosen and a button or buttons are revealed, is there an option to go back and click another image to get another button instead? or set of buttons? Do the images disappear once you have picked one of the images?

Answer (score 1):

You can add id's to your buttons and use the show/hide to show and hide the buttons that you want.

```
switch(jQuery(event.target).attr("data-designName")){
            case "pink Flower":
                //target = "first button";
                $("#id_of_button_that_you_want_to_hide").hide();
                break;
            case "red Rocks":
                $("#id_of_button_that_you_want_to_hide").hide();
                break;
            }
```

or you can make all of them disabled and remove the attribute of the ones that you want to display

```
<div id="buttons" style="display: none;"> 
  <ol>
  <li class="ui-state-default">
   <a id="firstButton" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background-position: -50px -0px" title="first button" data-designName="first button" disabled="true"></a>
  </li>
     <li class="ui-state-default">
 <a id="secondButton" href="javascript:void(0);" style="background-position: -80px -1px" title="second button" data-designName="second button" disabled="true"></a>
 </li>
```

```
switch(jQuery(event.target).attr("data-designName")){
                case "pink Flower":
                    //target = "first button";
                    $("#firstButton").attr("disabled", false);
                    break;
                case "red Rocks":
                    $("#secondButton").attr("disabled", false);
                    break;
                }
```